# ws-security-policy not getting applied to request from spawned thread on Websphere

Tags: web-services, websphere, quartz-scheduler, ws-security

I have a web-service client running inside a web-app on `Websphere 7` using `ws-security-policy`.

When the client is invoked from a web-session or the main thread in a context-listener, the request gets encrypted as per policies.

When called from a spawned thread from the context-listener however, the request goes as plain  SOAP. Why aren't policy handlers getting applied

I have also asked this question [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=ff54882d-da5d-4d27-873d-8d94a86c04e3)

Comment: Seems the issue is due to Quartz spawning a non-managed thread. Now I am looking for using something like Timer Service.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your Quartz job processing code (web service consumption) to a message driven bean (MDB) and change your job scheduling code to instead send a JMS message to the queue/destination instead of using non JavaEE threading (Quartz).  An advantage of consuming the web service from a MDB is that you can use JAX-WS annotations such as @WebServiceRef, just like you can in container managed components such as servlets and context listeners. This gives you container injection of managed web service clients that can be configured with security policies within the application server.

Comment: Thanks Scott. For now we have moved the execution code to a servlet called by an external cron job, the least impact solution.  In your solution, what is the scheduling component? If it is still Quartz, I am not sure if I will get the context back.

Comment: Timer service, as you pointed out. Since the bean is still container managed, your component scoped reference to a soap client will also be managed (injection or lookup) and should have your container managed policies intact.

Comment: With Time Service itself, the policies were getting applied by server. So, that would have solved the problem.